# Issue while installation of devops

Tags: managed-package

I was trying to install devops in my developer org and enabled source control from devhub and installed devops.
Enabled these permissions in the permission set for the system admin:

[image]

Enable the permission sf_devops_NamedCredentials for the connected app Devops
[image]

Still there is an issue while accessing the devops from the app launcher:

```
    This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
 [Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'appState')]
```

Why is this error popping up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have Debug Mode activated.

- Settings > Search "Debug Mode" & Disable it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/184647)